# Conceptual issue with bootstrap navbar: disable dropdown menu only for desktop but allow it on mobile?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm working with the [bootstrap basic](https://wordpress.org/themes/bootstrap-basic/) Wordpress theme which uses wp-bootstrap-navwalker.

I have one page (page X) on my site where I would like a sidebar menu to be displayed on the right side with sub-pages, while the main menu sits at the top.

I have used the advanced-sidebar-menu plugin that makes a sidebar menu based on the parent/child relationship (so under page X, there are a few child pages). Now, that automatically makes the parent page X a dropdown menu.

I would like this dropdown menu to be deactivated on desktops (or screens of a certain size) whereby you click on the page and it takes you to the first child of that page.

On mobile, I would like the dropdown to be shown and the sidebar to be hidden as it makes the navigation easier..

Hiding the sidebar isn't difficult. But it seems that with the dropdown menu, I can either have it on all the time or off all the time - ?

If I add the disabled class (class="dropdown-toggle disabled"), I can make the parent page X clickable and effectively hide the dropdown. However, then it doesn't work on mobile at all. If I don't add 'disabled' and hide the dropbox with CSS depending on screen size, Page X isn't clickable and therefore you can never see the child pages of Page X.

Is there a way of hiding the dropdown menu on desktops whereby clicking on the parent takes you to the first child page, AND enabling it on mobile?

Posting the code is a bit involved, so I've attached a screenshot of the menu instead. Basically, I don't want the dropdown to show on big screens but only on small screens...

[example menu with dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5arLh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example you can show hide a particular element on different screen size, hope this help, test this demo on different screen size

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

<div class="visible-xs  hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg text-info"><h1>Visible in xs devices</h1></div>
    <div class="visible-sm  hidden-xs hidden-md hidden-lg text-info"><h1>Visible in sm devices</h1></div>
    <div class="visible-md  hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-lg text-info"><h1>Visible in md devices</h1></div>
    <div class="visible-lg  hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-xs text-info"><h1>Visible in lg devices</h1></div>
```

Comment: thanks that almost works! but if I make the dropdown parent disabled (class="dropdown-toggle disabled") in order to make it clickable in the desktop version, it's not collapsible in the mobile menu (i.e. the subpages automatically show while normally you first click on the parent to show the subpages). Is there a way to only show the dropdown on mobile like with your method, but also have it fully functional?

Comment: yes, you can add two drop down one for desktop n one for mobile, just make dropdown for mobile n show it in mobile devices n for desktop use simple button..no need to make drop down for this case...or you can add visible-xs or visible-sm inside the tag  ul (that make drop down) or you can do this programitically by jquery by finding the type device you hv..once u get the type of device u hv just remove or add attribute data-toggle, so that it will show n hide accordingly..if this solution worked for you then kindly upvote n accept the answer..gud luck dude...

Comment: yes brilliant, I added two menu items in wordpress, one with subpages and one without. I then added the classes above and now one or the other only appears depending on screen size. cheers!